# How can I make java wait

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, while-loop, wait

I asked a question about my actual problem but no solution emerged so I'll try to be more open, how can I make java wait for a certain input? Presently I have a semi-infinite while loop that looks at a variable that doesn't get updated until an ActionEvent fires in another class. However I had read about threads and some other things, was curious if anyone could elaborate on this topic a bit? Basically I'm working on a GUI, my window pops up and asks for a password, and when the button is pressed that changes the variable to exit the loop. The strangest part is that it works on school computers but not my own. I even reinstalled my JDK, but that's not it. It came up that it might be a speed issue, but with print statements I see the variable gets updated, the while just stops looking at it I guess.

```
private static boolean running=true;

while(running){
}

...

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String temp = new String("");
    for(int x=0;x<passwordInput.getPassword().length;x++)
        temp+=passwordInput.getPassword()[x];
    PWCoder.passwordCheck(temp);
}

...

public static void passwordCheck(String pass){
if(pass.equals(password)){
    correctPW = true;
}
else if(pass.equals(overKey))
    PWCoder.override(password);
doneRunning();
}

...

public static void doneRunning(){
    running = false;
}
```

There's the code for what it'll help. Should be more or less in the order it would execute, but it's not all one block, being multiple classes and all. I attempted using volatile, that didn't do anything.

Comment: You'd have to share the relevant sections of your code

Comment: [How to use dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)?

Comment: Using a spin-lock to handle a modal dialog means that there is most likely a better way to implement what you're trying for. Try restructuring your code to be more event based, especially if you are using the default Swing UI classes.

Comment: @MadProgrammer A dialogue might do it, I experimented briefly with those, but the code works on one computer and not another. It's not the IDE or JDK, but I highly doubt it's a speed issue either.

Answer (score 1):

If you're updating and reading variable (presumably a primitive value) in multiple threads did  you declare the variable with the *volatile* keyword. For optimization your thread might have cached the value and not read the changed value --- volatile forces the JVM read the variable each time without caching it.

Other than declaring a variable volatile, you may consider using a *synchroinized* block to read/write the variable if not a primitive field and requires more than an atomic operation to read/write the value.

In your updated code example the *running* and *password* variables should be declared *volatile* like this:

```
private static volatile boolean running = true;
```

Comment: article about this: http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html

Comment: I did that, but being that nothing changed I did not include it in the code quote